# How return all positions of a given subarray of an array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Consider a Numpy array `C` of shape `(s_1,...,s_k)` and another array `A` of shape `(s_j,...,s_k)` where `j > 1`. Is there a function in Python to return the list `[p_1,...,p_l]` of positions of the form `p_r == [x_1,...,x_{j-1}]` such that `C[x_1,...,x_{j-1}] == A`?

I tried this manual method:

```py
import numpy as np

# C is an array of shape (3, 2, 3)
C = np.array([
    [[5, 7, 1], [0, 2, 1]],
    [[4, 7, 2], [-1, 2, 2]],
    [[3, 7, 3], [-3, 2, 3]]
])
# is an array of shape (3)
A = np.array([-1, 2, 2])
pos_list = []
for i in range(C.shape[0]):
    for j in range(C.shape[1]):
        if np.all(C[i, j] == A):
            # append to pos_list all elements [i, j] with 0 =< i =< 3, 0 =< j =< 2
            pos_list.append([i, j])

print(pos_list)
```

Output:

```py
[[1, 1]]
```

Comment: I think your question needs clarification. You state that you want `C[x_1,...,x_{j-1}] == A`, if you slice your array with your current output, i.e. `C[pos_list[0][0], pos_list[0][1], :]` that is equal to your array `A`

Answer (score 1):

`all` takes an axis parameter.

```
In [72]: C = np.array([
    ...:     [[5, 7, 1], [0, 2, 1]],
    ...:     [[4, 7, 2], [-1, 2, 2]],
    ...:     [[3, 7, 3], [-3, 2, 3]]
    ...: ])
    ...: # is an array of shape (3)
    ...: A = np.array([-1, 2, 2])

In [73]: C
Out[73]: 
array([[[ 5,  7,  1],
        [ 0,  2,  1]],

       [[ 4,  7,  2],
        [-1,  2,  2]],

       [[ 3,  7,  3],
        [-3,  2,  3]]])

In [74]: A
Out[74]: array([-1,  2,  2])
```

Since `A` is (3,) it will broadcast with `C`, returning a `C` shape boolean:

```
In [75]: C==A
Out[75]: 
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False]],

       [[False, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False]]])
```

then look for all 'rows' that are all true:

```
In [76]: (C==A).all(axis=-1)
Out[76]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

And get the indicies either with:

```
In [77]: np.nonzero(_)
Out[77]: (array([1], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))
```

or

```
In [78]: np.argwhere(__)
Out[78]: array([[1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: that form of output you got is very ugly and unusable because I want to use the position list as a range for a `for`-loop.

Comment: `nonzero`  is a tuple of arrays that can be used directly to index `B`, and fetch all matches.  `argwhere` takes the `transpose`, and can be used iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

A simple comparison will do this.  It produces a 3x2x3 boolean result, but you can do an `all` on the 3rd axis to find the complete matches, and then `where` to convert that to coordinates.

```
import numpy as np

C = np.array([
    [[5, 7, 1], [0, 2, 1]],
    [[4, 7, 2], [-1, 2, 2]],
    [[3, 7, 3], [-3, 2, 3]]
])

A = np.array([-1, 2, 2])

B = np.where(np.all(C==A,axis=2))
print(B)
```

Output:

```
(array([1]), array([1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers, we can start by using `==` to find which of the inner values of `C` match `A`. This check is done one-to-one, so `[-3, 2, 3]` will be `[False, True, False]` since the first and last values don't match but the middle does.

```py
In [1]: C == A
Out[1]:
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False]],

       [[False, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False]]])
```

We can then use `.all(axis=2)` to find which of those inner arrays are *all* `True`, which happens when the arrays match completely.

```py
In [2]: (C == A).all(axis=2)
Out[2]:
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

Since you want the indices of these, you can use `np.where`.

```py
In [3]: np.where((C == A).all(axis=2))
Out[3]: (array([1], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))
```

To format it in the same way you gave, we first convert the result into a numpy array.

```py
In [4]: np.array(np.where((C == A).all(axis=2)))
Out[4]: 
array([[1],
       [1]], dtype=int64)
```

Then we take the transpose to turn it into a row vector.

```py
In [5]: np.array(np.where((C == A).all(axis=2))).T
Out[5]: array([[1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Putting it all together:

```py
import numpy as np

C = np.array([[[5, 7, 1], [0, 2, 1]],
              [[4, 7, 2], [-1, 2, 2]],
              [[3, 7, 3], [-3, 2, 3]]])
A = np.array([-1, 2, 2])

res = np.array(np.where((C == A).all(axis=2))).T
print(res)
```

Output:

```py
[[1 1]]
```